# Python: pickle derived str object

Tags: python, string, cpython, pickle

Running:

```
import pickle

class Foo(str):
    def __new__(cls, s, bar):
        self = super(Foo, cls).__new__(cls, s)
        self.bar = bar
        return self

with open('foo.pkl', 'wb') as w:
    x = pickle.dump(Foo('', 1), w, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

with open('foo.pkl', 'rb') as w:
    x = pickle.load(w)
```

Results in this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pkl.py", line 13, in <module>
    x = pickle.load(w)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1083, in load_newobj
    obj = cls.__new__(cls, *args)
TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

It works, if I remove `pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL`, but I'd rather use the new protocol, if possible.

I'm just not getting the pickle protocol description. Can anyone help me out? There must be some way with magic methods...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works without the `HIGHEST_PROTOCOL` because the older protocols don't use the `__new__` constructor for unpickled objects.

But the basic is that you are using the serializing methods of `str` while you are adding a new argument to `__new__`. The `pickle` module nor the builtin `str` type has any knowledge of this and it will result in the error shown.

To fix it you should define the `__getnewargs__` method and return `(self.__class__, self.bar)` which should be sufficient for it to work again.

Documentation on the special methods used by the `pickle` module can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickling-and-unpickling-normal-class-instances)

Comment: This seems to work, but returning `(self, self.bar)` is wrong (RecursionError). I think I have to return `(self.__class__, self.bar)`. Thanks!

Comment: Ah indeed, sorry I don't use pickle too often myself. Edited it for future searches.

Comment: Even better would be to not derive from `str`, it is likely to lead to all sorts of complications.

Comment: @NedBatchelder Can you explain why? (Also this is a pretty special case, because it's just about the additional information in a file).

Comment: @Wessie I have to correct myself again: `(self.__class__, self.bar)` is also not true. It's `(str(self), self.bar)`. Because if there's no cast to str, there's a `RecursionError` (pickle want's to pickle `self`). My solution (previous comment) makes no sense, becase pickle knows the `cls` param.